# Triangular Distribution in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function, distribution, triangular

What I currently have:

```vba
Option Explicit

Function Triangular(a As Double, b As Double, c As Double) As Double

Randomize
Application.Volatile

Dim d As Double
Dim uniform As Double
Dim retval as Double 



d = (b - a) / (c - a)
    uniform = Rnd()

    If uniform <= d Then
    Triangular = a + (c - a) * Sqr(d * uniform)

Else

    Triangular = a + (c - a) * (1 - Sqr(1 - d) * (1 - uniform))

End If

End Function
```

I'm having trouble in  regards to creating a triangular distribution function in VBA, which calculates a random number from arguments made from:

- Calculate d = ( b - a )/( c - a )
- Generate a uniformly distributed random number U between 0 and 1 with VBA's Rnd function.
- If U <= d, return a + ( c - a ) × sqr(d×U) as the random number. (Sqr(x) is a VBA function which returns the square root of x.
- If U > d , return a + ( c - a ) × (1 - sqr((1- d )×(1-U))) as the random number.

The parameters a and c are the minimum and maximum possible values respectively, and
the parameter b is the most likely value (where you see the high point in the triangle).

I'm unsure on how to create this function and was wondering if someone could lend a hand? In working on the function I realize I need to use randomize function in order to not generate similar results each time the function is called, as well as the application.volatile operation.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in the code. Should be in second branch

```
Triangular = a + (c - a) * (1 - Sqr((1 - d) * (1 - uniform)))
```

Comment: would you happen to know how to write a sub after this that takes the  (a)min, (b)max, (c) likely, and total number of values, and display the specified
number of random values on a new worksheet?

Comment: @JaySmith no, I don't - never used VBA in my life. To be more precise, I know how to write triangular sampling, and did it before, but not in VBA and have no idea how to `display the specified number of random values on a new worksheet`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the correctness of your generating equations. Take a look [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution#Generating_triangular-distributed_random_variates) for the correct equations; with the difference that `b` and `c` are switched with respect to your definition. Here's an implementation adapting the formulas of that page to your own definitions of a, b and c:

```
Function Triangular(a As Double, b As Double, c As Double) As Double
    Application.Volatile
    Dim U As Double: U = Rnd()
    If U < (b - a) / (c - a) Then
      Triangular = a + sqrt(U * (b - a) * (c - a))
    Else
      Triangular = c - sqrt(U * (c - b) * (c - a))
    End If
End Function
```

---

To generate a sequence from the above distribution in a new Worksheet, you can

1- Create the new worksheet

2- Write your parameters in cells `A1`, `B1` and `C1`

3- write this formula in `A2`:  `=Triangular($A$1, $B$1, $C$1)`

4-  Copy/Paste cell A2 down the column

Answer (score 0):

Please notice **(1-Prob)** in the second case. The [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution#Generating_triangular-distributed_random_variates) shows the correct formula but it was not implemented correctly by A.S.H.

```
Function Triangular(ByVal Min As Single, ByVal ML As Single, ByVal Max As Single) As Single
    Application.Volatile
    Dim Prob As Single
    Prob = Rnd
    If Prob < (ML - Min) / (Max - Min) Then
      Triangular = Min + Sqr(Prob * (ML - Min) * (Max - Min))
    Else
      Triangular = Max - Sqr((1 - Prob) * (Max - ML) * (Max - Min))
    End If
End Function
```